# Angular strap show list of errors

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

Is it possible to show a list of errors (comma separated array) in angular strap alerts problematically or html?

I didn't find a way to do that.

```
$scope.errors = response.split(',');

var myAlert = $alert({
title: 'title',
content: '-----------',
placement: 'top',
type: 'success',
duration: '1',
show: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that array is created from comma delimited string ...just pass in original string

```
var myAlert = $alert({
    title: 'title',
    content: response,
    placement: 'top',
    type: 'success',
    duration: '1',
    show: true
});
```

Or for a bit more separation use `$scope.errors.join(', ');`

Comment: thank you, this works better for me $scope.errors = response.split(',').join('.<br />');

Comment: was going to suggest that also if `content` allows html